# Drawing background on wxMenu

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

There is no `SetBitmap` method to draw a background in `wxMenu` , so I tried to make a custom menu and try to listen for the `Paint` event and draw it as follow :

```
#ifndef CUSTOMMENU_H
#define CUSTOMMENU_H

#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <wx/dcclient.h>

class CustomMenu : public wxMenu
{
    public:
        //CustomMenu();
        CustomMenu(const wxBitmap &bmpBackground);
        virtual ~CustomMenu();

        void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event);

        wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
    protected:
    private:
       wxBitmap  bmpBackground;
};

#endif // CUSTOMMENU_H
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "CustomMenu.h"

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(CustomMenu, wxMenu)
    EVT_PAINT(CustomMenu::OnPaint)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

CustomMenu::CustomMenu(const wxBitmap &bmpBackground)
    :bmpBackground(bmpBackground)
{
}

CustomMenu::~CustomMenu()
{
    //dtor
}

void CustomMenu::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event){
    wxPaintDC paintDC(this);
    paintDC.DrawBitmap(bmpBackground,0,0);
}
```

but it throw this `error: no matching function for call to 'wxPaintDC::wxPaintDC(CustomMenu* const)'|`

how to go around this and draw a background image on a `wxMenu`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the standard `wxMenu`. Remember that wxWidgets provides you with *native* UI. Native menus don't support background images on none of the main platforms and so wxWidgets doesn't neither. If you absolutely need this, you will need to use your own custom menu-like widget (which won't be simple to implement and won't behave exactly the same as native menus neither, so it's really not advised).